# Word Topology deployment error

Tags: java, python, apache-storm, topology

I am getting the following error when I try to deploy the Word Topology in windows.

I have followed the below link to deploy the word Topology in windows.

http://ptgoetz.github.io/blog/2013/12/18/running-apache-storm-on-windows/

When i deploy and see I am getting the floowing error.

```
       java.lang.RuntimeException: Error when launching multilang subprocess

    at backtype.storm.task.ShellBolt.prepare(ShellBolt.java:105)
      at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__3493$fn__3505.invoke(executor.clj:689)
      at backtype.storm.util$async_loop$fn__457.invoke(util.clj:431)
       at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
        Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python" (in directory "storm- local\supervisor\stormdist\WordCount-1-1407303402\resources"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
     at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    at backtype.storm.utils.ShellProcess.launch(ShellProcess.java:50)
      at backtype.storm.task.ShellBolt.prepare(ShellBolt.java:102)
... 4 more
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
      at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
     at java.lang.ProcessImpl.(ProcessImpl.java:189)
      at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:133)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1021)
```

Can anyone help me.

Comment: have you installed python on your machine? In tutorial it is mentioned to install python

Comment: Yes, I have installed python but still I feel python only causing the problem. The resources folder files are not getting loaded properly

Comment: Maybe python just isn't in your PATH then?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error. 
Look at the compiled source. In the `target` folder you need all the scripts of the mutlilang available to execute all of them.

Look at `target/classes/resources/` if there are any files. If not and if even you do not have the folder in `target/classes` copy the the resource folder from `multilang/resources` into the target path.